# Ubuntu 18.04 - Second External Monitor not Working [Nvidia GTX 1650]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, dell

I searched on the web for many different solutions. Nothing worked.

**Situation:**
I have a Dell XPS 15 with a Nvidia GTX 1650.
Installed Ubuntu 18.04 and ran a tweak script (https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin/blob/master/xps-tweaks.sh) which adds the xorg configuration file: https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin/blob/master/10-prime-offload.conf. I use an original Dell docking station and have monitors linked with Display Port.

**Problem:**
I cannot connect two external monitors. One external monitor is working perfect.

1. Connecting the second external monitor during startup ends in a freeze.
2. Connecting after start up: The monitor is listed in "Displays" Settings of Ubuntu. But I cannot active it. Running the command `xrandr --output DP-1-2 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 3840x0 --rotate normal` is not working with error: `xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed`. When I activate the display in the Display settings, it gets switched off after applying the changes.

I have nvidia-prime installed and selected nvidia as the default gpu.

I have the driver: nvidia-driver-435 (open source) installed. Tried also with different kernels as I read that there probably is a problem. Now running on **5.2.17-050217-generic**.

When changing to terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F2 / F3) all three displays are showing up as mirrors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would check different versions of driver. 
In my case nvidia-418 is the newest one, with works properly with external monitors.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx
```